# Changing an input's HTML5 placeholder color with CSS does not work on Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, placeholder

I tried to follow the following topic, but unsuccessfully.
[Change an HTML5 input's placeholder color with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css)

I tried to colorize my placeholder, but it still stay grey on Chrome 17.0.963.56 m.

**HTML**

```
<input type='text' name='test' placeholder='colorize placeholder' value='' />
```

**CSS**

```
INPUT::-webkit-input-placeholder, 
INPUT:-moz-placeholder {
    color:red;
}
input[placeholder], [placeholder], *[placeholder]
{
    color:green !important;
}
```

**JSfiddle**

- http://jsfiddle.net/F4xfV/1/

On Firefox 10.0.2, it works well.

Comment: If you're using a CSS framework like Bootstrap, they might already have these styles defined, so you have to add `!important`, or make sure everything cascades as intended.

Comment: `!important` did the trick for me. Without that, the placeholder text colour remained frustratingly unchangeable, even while other font attributes could be changed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change an input's HTML5 placeholder color with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css)

Comment: @fuxia, not a duplicate, since it I started with the question you quote (I quote it too in my question), then I had a problem with, that's why I asked this question.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You forget a `:`.
Because of that, the whole selector got corrupted and didn't work.
http://jsfiddle.net/a96f6/87/

Edit:
Seems like (after an update?) this doesn't work anymore, try this:

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder{
    color:red;
}
input:-moz-placeholder {
    color:red;
}
```

Note: don't mix the vendor prefix selectors (-moz, -webkit, -ms, ...). Chrome for example won't understand "-moz-" and then ignores the whole selector.

**Edit for clarification:**
To make it work in all browsers, use this code:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color:red;
}

::-moz-placeholder {
    color:red;
}

::-ms-placeholder {
    color:red;
}

::placeholder {
    color:red;
}
```

​

Comment: Thanks !
your were right.

New rules are : 
`input::-webkit-input-placeholder, 
input::-moz-placeholder {
    color:red;
}`

Comment: Isn’t that `input:-moz-placeholder { color:red; }` instead? That’s what’s in the other thread. Also, do not put both selectors in one rule.

Comment: placeholder color is not red in my chrome  29.0.1547.57

Comment: css code still works for me, but the fiddle was outdated.
http://jsfiddle.net/a96f6/87/

Comment: Note to add to this answer is Firefox 19+ placeholder is: `input::-moz-placeholder { color: red;}` notice the additional `:`.

Comment: "Don't mix the vendor prefix" - this tripped me up for HOURS!

Comment: @iciPiracy: I successfully tested the fiddle in Chrome, Safari and Firefox. Sadly no Edge/IE available. In what browsers do you encounter problems?

Comment: @Dmitry please don't make substantive edits to the code of another user's answer. Add your own answer, instead!

Comment: @TylerH sorry, I just thought my addition was more like comment on another answer, so I decided to amend an existing answer

Comment: Added a separate answer. It now duplicates part of this answer in order to provide context.

Comment: Don't put them all together, separated by commas, it doesn't seem to work. 
I encounter issues with Firefox and later when I separate them as shown above, they work as they were supposed to.

Comment: You provided a better answer than w3schools :D https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_placeholder.asp

Answer (score 48):

As @Alex said, for some reason you can't combine the selectors for multiple browsers.

This **will work**

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color:red;
}

::-moz-placeholder {
    color:red;
}

::-ms-placeholder {
    color:red;
}

::placeholder {
    color:red;
}
```

But this **won't work** (in Chrome at least):

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder,
::-moz-placeholder,
::-ms-placeholder,
::placeholder {
    color:red;
}
```

Looks like a browser implementation quirk to me.

Also, note that you don't have to define placeholder styles globally, you can still scope the `::placeholder` selector just like you normally do. This works:

```
.my-form .input-text::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color:red;
}

.my-form .input-text::-moz-placeholder {
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: thanks for mentioning what **won't** work, thats where i was screwing up

Comment: Does anyone know why the first way doesn't work? I thought that was just really common css syntax. So confused

Comment: Additionally, this **will NOT work** either (in Chrome at least):
`.my-form .input-text::-webkit-input-placeholder, .my-second-form .input-text::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: red;
}`

Answer (score 6):

I  have just experienced  the same problem and thought it would be good to share.
For some reason, the color was not changing on firefox and I noticed that its only when I use hexadecimal values so I did it this way for a particular website:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #666666;
}

::-moz-placeholder {
    color: black;
}

::-ms-placeholder {
    color: #666666;
}

::placeholder {
    color: #666666;
}
```

Comment: No other answer was working for me!  This placeholder thing is weird... can't combine vendor-prefixed selectors, can't use named colors...

Comment: What I noticed was that firefox lightens the color you choose. If you choose red it looks a bit pink, not the bright red that red would usually be.

Answer (score 1):

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #008000;
}
```