# change placeholder text color of textarea

Tags: html, css

I know there is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-html5-inputs-placeholder-color-with-css) post on changing the placeholder text. I've tried implementing in on my textarea tags

```
textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
color: #fff;
}

textarea:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
color: #fff;  
}

textarea::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
color: #fff;  
}

textarea:-ms-input-placeholder {
color: #fff;  
}
```

but it's not doing anything. What am I missing?

This is what one of my `textarea`'s looks like

```
<textarea
  onChange={(e) => this.props.handleUpdateQuestion(e, firstQuestion.Id)}
  placeholder="Overall Satisfaction Question"
  name="SEO__Question__c"
  type="text"
  className="slds-input"
  value={firstQuestion.SEO__Question__c ? firstQuestion.SEO__Question__c : ''}
  style={inputStyle}
  autoFocus
/>
```

Comment: `color: #fff;` :) I'm afraid to ask: *what's your background color* ;) - Yeah, I mean your code works just fine otherwise... Chrome at least.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan it's a dark image, with a clear input. No white background. :)

Comment: I needed this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451902/changing-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css-does-not-work-on-chrome

Answer (score 72, accepted):

For modern browsers, use just the [::placeholder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder) pseudo element:

```js
textarea::placeholder {
  color: #0bf;
}
```

Legacy and modern browsers:

```css
textarea:-moz-placeholder, /* Firefox 18- */
textarea::-moz-placeholder, /* Firefox 19+ */
textarea:-ms-input-placeholder, /* IE 10+ */
textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder, /* Webkit based */
textarea::placeholder { /* Modern browsers */
  color: #0bf;  
}
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="test"></textarea>
```

And related to your code, wrap in quotes:

```
onchange="{(e) => this.props.handleUpdateQuestion(e, firstQuestion.Id)}"
```

Answer (score 23):

I am not sure but I think is not necessary to use the prefixes right now.

```
textarea::placeholder {
  color: #fff;  
}
```

Comment: You can find an article in Mozilla Developers website that contains compatibility information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder#Browser_compatibility. TLDR: prefix is still required for some browsers.

Comment: Safari (v12) still requires prefix today

Answer (score 0):

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
       color: orange;
    }
    :-moz-placeholder { /* Upto Firefox 18, Deprecated in Firefox 19  */
       color: orange;  
    }
    ::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
       color: orange;  
    }
    :-ms-input-placeholder {  
       color: orange;  
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

textarea::placeholder {color: #fff;}