# how can i change html5 textarea placeholder color?

Tags: html, css

i am trying to change input and textarea placeholder color. but it is just work on input. it is does not work on textarea placeholder color. how can i change textarea placeholder color?[enter image description here][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8esKN.png
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCvE3.png

Answer (score 3):

I had the same prob before.

try this here:

```
textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
color: #0bf;
}

textarea:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
color: #0bf;  
}

textarea::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
color: #0bf;  
}

textarea:-ms-input-placeholder {
color: #0bf;  
}
```

found on
[change placeholder text color of textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43793639/change-placeholder-text-color-of-textarea)