# How do I change the properties of a textarea depending on whether it is being typed into

Tags: html, css, textarea

So I have a website, and I have a text area. The background is white and the text is black. How do I make the background color and color change when it is being typed into?

Comment: Please share a code snippet of what you have already done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use :focus pseudo code

```css
textarea:focus {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks. I woud just like to ask another quick question: how can I change the properties of a textarea placeholder

Comment: @JefferyJohnson https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43793639/change-placeholder-text-color-of-textarea

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id= "textId">
    My text
</textarea>

<div id="colorChange">My DIV</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var textAr = document.getElementById("textId");
    var colorDiv = document.getElementById("colorChange");

    function changeColor(){
        colorDiv.style.color = "blue";
    }

    textAr.addEventListener('keyup',changeColor);
</script>
```