# placeholder style not working in chrome?

Tags: html, css

I have this code working perfectly in chrome and Internet Explorer.But whenever I combine the CSS style like below, It is only working in Internet explorer but not in chrome.

Does anybody about this peculiar behavior?

```css
.searchBar{
 height:50px;
 width:200px;
 background-color:#9a005f;
 color:#fff;
}
.searchBar:focus{
 background-color:#9a445f;
}
.searchBar::-webkit-input-placeholder{
color:#fff;
}
.searchBar::-ms-input-placeholder{
 color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="searchBar" placeholder="Search for..."/>
```

**EDIT :**
The below is not working in my chrome but working in IE.

```css
.searchBar{
 height:50px;
 width:200px;
 background-color:#9a005f;
 color:#fff;
}
.searchBar:focus{
 background-color:#9a445f;
}
.searchBar::-webkit-input-placeholder,
.searchBar::-ms-input-placeholder{
    color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="searchBar" placeholder="Search for..."/>
```

Comment: Chrome has not been a webkit browser in several years and most vendor prefixes are behind a flag now so I'm not surprised that what you're doing doesn't work.

Comment: Then why it works for `.searchBar::-webkit-input-placeholder` alone ?

Comment: Well, I just noticed you are missing the '.' on the second line. Chrome does follow many webkit prefixes but I don't think they do that for any newer ones. Obviously it does for placeholder.

Comment: Your code snippet works on my chrome.

Comment: Works on my Chrome, too. 60.0.3112.90 64 bits

Comment: it is working...

Answer (score 8):

I've done some search on internet and I've found what I believe is [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451902/changing-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css-does-not-work-on-chrome) to your question.

> Don't mix the vendor prefix selectors (-moz, -webkit, -ms, ...).
>   Chrome for example won't understand "-moz-" and then ignores the whole
>   selector.