# Colors in CSS based on Browser

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage & the colors are washed out in Chrome.
The pic below shows the exact same URL with the left side on Firefox & the right side on Chrome.

It is not so subtle, for example, the text 'Search...' inside the search bar is not visible at all!!

The shadow provides a slight 3D effect & this is almost completely wiped out in Chrome!

I have searched this issue & almost all solution seem to suggest the person who visits the page should make somekind of adjustment at their end & I cannot go around telling all the visitors to the website to do that.

So, my question is, can the colors be specified based on the browser in CSS?

The running app can be found here [eaterydemo.netlify.app/menu](https://eaterydemo.netlify.app/menu)

```css
.container {
display: flex; gap:12px;
flex-direction: column}

.item {
  margin: 0 1rem 0;
  padding: 0.5rem 1.1rem 0.5rem;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    hsl(18, 64%, 59%) 0.25rem,
    hsl(220, 20%, 97%) 0% 100%
  );
  color: hsl(188, 95%, 7%);
  border-radius: 0.25rem 0.25rem 0.25rem 0.25rem;      
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  filter: drop-shadow(0.05rem 0.05rem 0.05rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
  z-index: 2;
}

.search-bar {
  display: inline-block;
  width: clamp(80px, 15vw, 120px);
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  background: hsl(220, 13%, 28%, 0.8);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin:1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="item">
      <span className="item">Rest</span>
      <span className="price">₹ 50</span>
</div>
<div class="item">
      <span className="item">Rest</span>
      <span className="price">₹ 50</span>
</div>
<div class="item">
      <span className="item">Rest</span>
      <span className="price">₹ 50</span>
</div>
<div class="item">
      <span className="item">Rest</span>
      <span className="price">₹ 50</span>
</div>
</div>

<div class="search-container">
      <input
        class="search-bar"
        type= "search"
        placeholder="Search..." />
 </div>
```

[image]

Comment: How does the existing stylesheet looks like for the given field? Can you please provide a minimal working example?

Comment: I have put a minimal working example.

Comment: PS, you need a semicolon after `border: 1px solid blue` in your CSS.

Comment: Have you tried using `box-shadow: 0.05rem 0.05rem 0.2rem rgb(0 0 0 / 50%);` under .item instead of `filter: drop-shadow`?

Comment: @NicolasGoosen Using the `box-shadow` instead of `filter: drop-shadow` worked! I had used 'filter: drop-shadow` because I though that I would get the shadow without the border radius. So, thanks. I have now added the search bar also in the minimal working example (the text 'Search...' is barely visible in Chrome), any suggestion on that?

Comment: I think it's a matter of using a proper reset. Resets are css libraries that focus on f giving a consistent base so any styles on top of them behave equally between browsers. You can try adding one before any css (like normalize css)

Comment: I have already used a reset in my project from here https://www.joshwcomeau.com/css/custom-css-reset/ Can you provide any other rest I should use, especially related to color since I am having issues with color.

Comment: @NicolasGoosen If you can put your suggestion as the answer I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `box-shadow: 0.05rem 0.05rem 0.2rem rgb(0 0 0 / 50%);` under **.item** instead of `filter: drop-shadow`?

Answer (score 1):

the reason Search text is not visible properly is because you are not applying css to it. Browsers behave differently for pseudo elements, in your case ::placeholder. No css has been applied to it.

```
.SearchBar_search-bar__3hLMw::placeholder {
    color: hsl(var(--font-color-primary));
}
```

and regarding shadow I couldn't see the issue on my Chrome and Firefox, but on Safari dropshadow filter is not working. Instead filter you can use box-shadow as it will work on all browsers.

Comment: I just figured out the `placeholder` issue from this post as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451902/changing-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css-does-not-work-on-chrome up-voted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, colours can't be specified based on the browser in CSS. You can detect the browser in javascript (see [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-detect-the-user-browser-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-using-javascript/#:%7E:text=Like%20Article-,How%20to%20detect%20the%20user%20browser%20(%20Safari%2C%20Chrome%2C%20IE,Firefox%20and%20Opera%20)%20using%20JavaScript%20%3F&text=The%20browser%20on%20which%20the,string%20sent%20by%20the%20browser.)), but not directly from inside CSS. It's not necessarily a good (sustainable) idea, though.

My suggestion would be to show us your CSS. It's very odd that Chrome would be showing this so wrong. Perhaps your CSS is using prefixed properties and you need to move on to using the regular properties.

Comment: what do you mean by `prefixed properties`? I am using a CSS custom variable and calling the variable in the components of my React app.

Comment: prefixed properties are properties which start with `-moz`, `-webkit`, etc., e.g., `-moz-column-count`. They are used by browser vendors for non-standard or not-yet-standardized properties. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083056/what-are-moz-and-webkit

Comment: ok. Understood. However, I do not use any `prefixed properties` in my css.